# closed form solution of the following iterative equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

is it possible to obtain a closed-form solution w.r.t. ${P_j:\forall j}$ (or in terms of special functions) for the following equations:

$\frac{\lambda}{\mu}P_0=P_1$

$\frac{\lambda}{\mu}P_j=P_{j+1}+P_{j+2}+\dots+P_{2j+1}$ for $j=1,2,....$

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty P_i=1$

$0<\lambda<\mu$

$P_i>0, \ \forall i=0,1,2,\dots$

Comment: That's all we are given?  No boundary values?  If, say, we take $P_0=0$ then we get $P_1=0$ and $P_2+P_3=0$, but after that...$P_4$ and $P_5$ only appear when added together, so we can set $P_4$ to whatever we like (and adjust $P_5$ to fit the sum).  So I don't see how your system determines any values beyond $P_1$.

Comment: sorry, i added one more condition which is missing in my previous post.

Comment: Doesn't help.  If you had any solution, I could switch $P_4,P_5$, say, and get another one.

Comment: I assume you meant $\sum P_i$.  And why write the constant coefficient as a fraction?  Seems odd.

Comment: sorry, typo. i think $P_4$ and $P_5$ are not exchangeable. Since when $j=3$, $P_4+P_5$ appears, but when $j=4, 5$, $P_4$ and $P_5$ do not appear as a sum.

Comment: Fair enough...let me think a bit....

Comment: thanks for your help. The final solution for $P_n$ can be expressed in terms of special functions. Also, let me give you the background of my problem. Actually, i want to find the steady distribution of the following random process: for very small time interval $\Delta t$, $x(t+\Delta t)=x(t)+1$, w.p. $\lambda \Delta t$,  $x(t+\Delta t)=\lfloor x(t)/2 \rfloor$, w.p. $\mu \Delta t$, and $x(t+\Delta t)=x(t)$, w.p. $1-\lambda \Delta t-\mu \Delta t$. I obtained the transition kernel $\mathbf{P}$ and use $\pi^T \mathbf{P} = \pi$ which leads to the above equations.

Comment: Sorry, still not seeing it.  Perhaps I am missing something.  It seems to me that if $P_0$ is known, then of course $P_1$ is known, but then I just get an expression for $P_2+P_3$.  If I then choose a value for $P_2$, I can know $P_3$...but then I just get an expression for $P_4+P_5$.  I don't see how to make unique choices.  And if, by a miracle, I get a convergent sum I can divide through by the value to satisfy your sum.  Of course, I have no idea if it is even possible to get a convergent sum here.  Is it?

Comment: I'll revisit the question in the morning.  No time now.  Sorry!

Comment: i guess there may be some kind of self-similarity property for such a sequence. Also, based on the random process in my previous post which directly relates to the above systems of equations, there shouldn't be any freedom and the solution should be unique. Thanks again for your help and  i will try different ways to solve. Look forward to discussing with you tmr :-)

Comment: My best guess:  you also want to require something about $\sum_{i=2j+1}^{\infty} P_i$:  Rearranging your equation, and writing $C=\frac {\lambda}{\mu}$ we get $C(1-P_0)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P_i+\sum_{i=3}^{\infty} P_i+\dots$.  That seems like a strong condition.  Absent that...well, as I say, it appears to me that I can make many choices starting from a given $P_0$.  I can, for example, make $P_{2k}=0$ for $k≥1$.  I don't think that convergence alone is enough to rule out all the options...

Comment: add some missing condition based on my original application scenario. would that help?

Comment: It might.  I like that iterated sum equation I wrote in my last comment.  It certainly seems that this ought to be recognizable (i haven't spotted it yet, but that doesn't mean someone else won't).

Comment: As a suggestion:  you might want to post the steady state problem as a separate question.  I'm only thinking about the iteration pattern...someone else might recognize the diffusion process.